# How to get rid of mixed language in Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2017

Tags: ssms

A German version of SSMS 2017 is already preinstalled on my machine. I want to get the English version.

After re-installing the English version, my UI is mixed up with half English, half German.

How do I get a clean installation without mixed languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Uninstall SSMS
2. Uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)
3. Re-install SSMS-ENG and it'll be fine.

Note: SSMS 2017 is a plugin of VS2015 Shell, if you have a non-English Shell, SSMS won't be shown in English.

Credits: Got the answer by working through this [msdn forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8fee4a33-13a6-47ec-9a1a-f0bfa9cf6c38/cant-change-ui-language-of-sql-server-management-studio-171-to-english).